# rowKey="#{dat.name}": The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'name'

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to make primefaces data table from this [link](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml) (second table with just one selection).

This is my code for xhtml:

```
<h:form>
<p:dataTable value="#{security.data}" var="dat" selectionMode="single" selection="#{security.selected}" rowKey="#{dat.name}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        List of Customers
    </f:facet>
    <p:column headerText="Customer">
        <h:outputText value="#{dat.name}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Contact">
        <h:outputText value="#{dat.contact}" />
    </p:column>
    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search" value="View" action="#{security.editCustomer()}" />
    </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>   
</h:form>
```

Security is my managedbean with a list "data" and string variable "selected".

For some reason I am getting error that 'dat' is a string and 'name' is not its member. I am properly defining getter in the bean:-

```
private List<customerData> data;

public security()
{
    data= new ArrayList<>();
    data.add(new customerData("Name1","264"));
}

public List<customerData> getData()
{
    return data;
}
```

"CustomerData" contains "name" attribute.

Comment: I think that the `selected` variable should be of type `customerData`

Comment: _""CustomerData" contains "name" attribute."_ : prove it, by posting code ;-) And how is the security class (lower case s???) made into a managed bean?

Comment: @OuerghiYassine you are right. I made this silly mistake of datatype. THANKS!!!!